# Detecting very tiny defect on a bottle using opencv3 C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I have an image in greyscale and it has a tiny defect, I am a beginner in computer vision. I tried the normal steps which are:

1. get image from high quality grey-scale cam.
2. default opencv histogram.
3. binary threshold (getting the mask).
4. removing background.
5. I tried playing with min and max (erode and dilate) to make defects bigger so I can detect it but lots of black dots come up with it. I tried blurring, weighted gradient, clahe and more but non worked with me.

That's the original image I get from the cam:

[image: original image]

My questions is :

1. how to make defects darker (less intensity value) than all the image contrast so I can loop and detect them?
2. if Q1 is not possible, what is a clear approach for this problem?

Comment: The bottle shows no defect, feel reassured.

Comment: I drew circles around the defect, the link shows the original image and the image with circles showing defects. scroll down pls

Comment: I would definitely start with better light positioning. First you have to position the light and the camera so you can >see< the defects no matter where they are, then the vision part is much easier and robust. Cant really think of robust approch to the problem with the image you ve provided.

Comment: @Croolman okay but until I fix the pic, what is the vision approach I should follow? is there a fixed one or it all depends on the output?

Answer (score 0):

The defects are really faint. Histogram equalization will give you a feeling that they are clearly visible, but this is not so true.

Especially in non flat zones, it won't be possible to separate the defects from the normal features, which any processing will enhance as well.